# jquery event not triggered the second time

Tags: jquery

I have a twitter like number count down for my text area that is part of a form:

```
<form method="post" id="myemailform" action="">
<label for="ReferralMessage">Optional message:</label><textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <span class="countdown"></span>
</form>
```

My jQuery 1.8.3 code for this:

```
function updateCountdown() {

    var remaining = 300 - jQuery('.message').val().length;
    jQuery('#myemailform button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
    if (remaining < 0){
        jQuery('.countdown').text(remaining).css({'color': 'red'});
        jQuery('#myemailform button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    if (remaining >= 0){
        jQuery('.countdown').text(remaining).css({'color': 'black'});
    }
}

jQuery(function() {

    var remaining = 300;
    //print amount currently
    jQuery('.countdown').text(remaining);
    //now update with changes
    jQuery('.message').on('input tap', updateCountdown);
});
```

This works great until the form is submitted. The page is refreshed but now the count down doesn't work anymore.

Although if I refresh manually it starts working again. Why is the event not triggering after the initial form submit?

Comment: could you provide a link to the working example?

Comment: I'm afraid it is a closed dev site.

Comment: thanks Tom. could you check 1) if jQuery is present after form submission 2) if there are any errors in your console after form submission 3) console.log() inside `updateCountdown` and see if anything gets logged after form submission

Comment: @darshanags no errors, jQuery is present. If I put `console.log('What is remaining char '+remaining);` it always shows `300` as I type in the text box. So the `updateCountdown` is firing but it just doesn't update...??

Comment: The only reason the remainder would show 300 is if `jQuery('.message').val().length` returns 0. I've copied and pasted this exact code into a local file and it works both before and after form submission. I would really like to help more but with the given information, this is as far as I can go. Sorry.

Comment: @darshanags thanks for looking. I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh. Nothing wrong with the code. It was a conflict with my selector. I used `message` as the name for my text box. It seemed to conflict with other things. So simple fix is to change it:

```
<form method="post" id="myemailform" action="">
<label for="ReferralMessage">Optional message:</label><textarea class="optionalmessage" name="optionalmessage"></textarea>
    <span class="countdown"></span>
</form>
```